# Instagram Graph API にて、メディアIDからユーザー情報を取得する方法はありますか？

Tags: instagram

表題の通り、Instagram Graph APIを使って、メディアIDからユーザー情報を取得したいと思っております。

流れとしては、以下の通りを考えております。

1. ハッシュタグ検索で、ハッシュタグIDを取得する。
2. ハッシュタグIDを使って、投稿メディアリストを取得する。
3. メディアIDからユーザー情報（userID,username,follower_coumtなど）を取得する

１・２は、APIを使って実現ができましたが、３に関しては、調べても出てきませんでした。

※自身のユーザー情報ではなく、他人のユーザー情報を取得したいです。

こちらの件、ご教授いただけますと幸いです。
ご回答のほど、よろしくお願いいたします。

使ったツール
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: [InstagramグラフAPI: IGハッシュタグ付きの最近のメディア](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-hashtag/recent-media) には、「返されたメディアオブジェクトのusernameフィールドをリクエストすることはできません」「個人を特定可能な情報は応答に含まれません」と記載されています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。どんな手法でも構わないのですが、他人のメディアIDからユーザー情報を取得する方法は知りませんでしょうか？